# How can I view a message I sent with an e-mail client (Thunderbird, Outlook...) via POP3 in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, outlook, thunderbird

When I send an e-mail using an e-mail client this mail does not appear in the "Sent" category in Gmail (the online application). But this mail must be stored someway in an accessible place because if this mail I sent gets an answer both my original message and the reply appear.

Is there any way I can view those sent messages without having to wait for a reply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be in your `All Mail` folder.

If it is a new email it will be there on it's own, if it is a reply or forward it will be threaded with the original email that you replied to or forwarded.

If you use IMAP instead of POP3 (at least in Thunderbird, not sure about Outlook) you can set it to place the sent items in your GMail sent item on the server.

Answer (score -2):

You need to set the option of saving copies of messages in Sent Items folder.
In **Outlook client**:
On the the E-Mail Options dialog, tick the setting for Saving copies of messages in Sent Items foder

Comment: -1 OP wants to know where to find the sent item in online GMail, not in local POP3 client.

Comment: Shevek is right